# Android JSON parsing same attribute

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON response like this :

```
 images: [

{

small: "/productimages/247DRFS100374LAV/small/247DRFS100374LAV_1.jpg",

medium: "/productimages/247DRFS100374LAV/medium/247DRFS100374LAV_1.jpg",

large: "/productimages/247DRFS100374LAV/large/247DRFS100374LAV_1.jpg"

},

{

small: "/productimages/247DRFS100374LAV/small/247DRFS100374LAV_2.jpg",

medium: "/productimages/247DRFS100374LAV/medium/247DRFS100374LAV_2.jpg",

large: "/productimages/247DRFS100374LAV/large/247DRFS100374LAV_2.jpg"

}

],
```

Since, the Image attribute gives 2 objects with exact same attributes (Small, medium and large), I want to extract only large images from both objects. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [GSON library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Define a class representing your images such as:

```
public class AppImage {
    @SerializedName("small")
    public string SmallImageUrl;

    @SerializedName("medium")
    public string MediumImageUrl;

    @SerializedName("large")
    public string LargeImageUrl;
}
```

And then deserialize it to an array like so:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type imageListType = new TypeToken<List<AppImage>>() {}.getType();
List<AppImage> images = gson.fromJson(json, imageListType);
```

Answer (score 0):

After researching a bit and applying algorithms, I found a more simple solution for my question.

```
JSONArray imgArray = response.getJSONArray("images");

    for (int i = 0; i < imgArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject displayPicObject = imgArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String detailPicture = displayPicObject.getString("large");
    }
```

now, for each iteration, I'm gonna get the next large image. I really appreciate your efforts to answer my question. Thanks a lot. :)